# Making an svn repository with all the files, but none of the history of an existing one?

Tags: svn

What's the easiest way to make a new svn repository that contains all the files, and structure of an existing repository, but that contains none of the history or versioning information?

Comment: Export from the existing repository and then create a new repository from that export.

Answer (score 0):

Export from the existing repository and then create a new repository from that export.  (Just copying +arkascha excellent answer so more folks notice it.)